# get output from a javascript file into a javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I want to run a js file (as if it were a frontend) in nodejs.

index.js:

```js
const a = 'dk3';

console.log(a)
```

logs.js:

```js
const logs = // exporting the file output above

console.log(logs)
```

the terminal of logs.js: dk3

how to do something like that? the index file cannot have anything to do with the logs, the log has to execute the index and return the output of the index as if it were a variable

edit: I got a part through this code:

index.js:

```js
console.log('foi')
```

logs.js:

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec('node src/console.js', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(`log: ${stdout}`);
})
```

output of logs.js: foi

but the index runs as nodejs, and I wanted it to be frontend, as if it were running in the html

Comment: What do you mean by "as if it were a frontend"? Are you trying to prompt the user for input as a command line program? Are you trying to run `index.js` as a child process of `logs.js`, and capture the output of `index.js`?

Comment: that! but the only problem is that index.js comes out as a backend, and I wanted it to run as a frontend

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "backend" and "frontend" for us to be able to properly answer your question. I know you say you want it "as if it were running in the HTML", but I do not understand what you mean by that. Do you want to create a webpage, and then have a backend node process getting output from the webpage?

Comment: So you want `index.js` to be executed in the browser?

Comment: I'm making a bot for discord that you put the javascript command line and he interprets, I don't want the person who will execute the commands to have access to require or things that break the code, so I think an interesting way would be to make the code was interpreted as if it were part of an html (the <script>). In short, I want this code to be sort of executed in the browser and the result of the code back to logs.js.

maybe if there was a way to not allow the user to use commands like require to access other files, I would also be satisfied

Comment: You can do that by providing your own custom wrapper over [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Your bot can get the input, sanitize it to remove unsafe stuff, and then feed it to `eval()`, then output the output of `eval()`. Or maybe you could consider some sort of sandbox approach.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is you are asking how to run `index.js` as a child process of the `node` process running `logs.js`, and that you want the code in `logs.js` to capture the `stdout` of the `index.js` child process, and then output the output of the child process to its own `stdout`.

You can synchronously execute a child process with [`child_process.spawnSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) (Node v0.11.12+).

You can use this for `logs.js`:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

const child = child_process.spawnSync('node', ['index.js'], { encoding : 'utf8' });

console.log(child.stdout);
```

Comment: yes, i got it a few minutes ago, but index.js still runs as nodejs (backend) and I wanted it to run as a frontend, as if it were running in the html <script>